# Python Script to convert Image into Byte array

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script where I want to do bulk photo upload.
I want to read an Image and convert it into a byte array. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import SOAPpy, getpass, datetime
import urllib, cStringIO
from PIL import Image
from urllib import urlopen 
import os
import io
from array import array
""" create a proxy object with methods that can be used to invoke
    corresponding RPC calls on the remote server """
soapy = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy('localhost:8090/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2?wsdl') 
auth = soapy.login('admin', 'Cs$corp@123')
```

Comment: why would you want that? how would that help you to upload? theres not enough data for a meaningful answer

Comment: @WeaselFox : I want to read an Image file and convert it into Byte array.

Comment: #pictureData = xmlrpclib.Binary(open('C:/BulkPhotoUpload/UserPhotos/admin.png').read()).decode('utf-8')
    url = 'C:/BulkPhotoUpload/UserPhotos/admin.png'
    pictureData = unicode(str(open(url,"rb")))
    print type(pictureData)
    profilePictureAdded = soapy.addProfilePicture(auth, 'admin', 'avatar.png', 'image/png', pictureData)
    if profilePictureAdded:
        print "Successfully added new profile picture..."
    else:
        print "Failed to add new profile picture..."

Comment: @WeaselFox I was looking this question to my odoo module. I upload an image to an S3 and I wanted to create a thumbnail on the fly, thanks to this question I can :)

Answer (score 90):

Use `bytearray`:

```
with open("img.png", "rb") as image:
  f = image.read()
  b = bytearray(f)
  print b[0]
```

You can also have a look at [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) which can do many conversions of that kind.

Comment: BTW. It is more meaningful to do that with image formats where you can directly interpret the data, which is the case for instance with the PNM family (PBM, PGM, PPM).

Comment: How to do the reverse of this conversion, i.e. converting bytearray to image?

Comment: I like it because it is the most basic, I have a shortage of `rb`

Answer (score 20):

This works for me

```
# Convert image to bytes
import PIL.Image as Image
pil_im = Image.fromarray(image)
b = io.BytesIO()
pil_im.save(b, 'jpeg')
im_bytes = b.getvalue()
```

Comment: What are you returning? - there's no function defined

Comment: @Ghoul Fool I copied it from my original function .. updated the answer to remove the `return` statement. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

i don't know about converting into a byte array, but it's easy to convert it into a string:

```
import base64

with open("t.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print str
```

[Source](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/convert-image-to-string-in-python/)

Comment: What's the best way to decode it, let's say into a PNG file??

Answer (score 6):

```
with BytesIO() as output:
    from PIL import Image
    with Image.open(filename) as img:
        img.convert('RGB').save(output, 'BMP')                
    data = output.getvalue()[14:]
```

I just use this for add a image to clipboard in windows.

Comment: So BytesIO() is from the io package (io.BytesIO()).  I tried this code but it gave me the error AttributeError: __exit__

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#__usage__ = "To Convert Image pixel data to readable bytes"

import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import *

class Image2ByteConverter(object):

    def loadImage(self):
        # Load image as string from file/database
        file = open('Aiming_ECU_Image.png', "rb")
        return file

    def convertImage2Byte(self):
        file = self.loadImage()
        pixel_data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=np.uint8)
        return pixel_data

    def printData(self):
        final_data = self.convertImage2Byte()
        pixel_count = 0
        for data in final_data:
            pixel_count += 1
            print("Byte ", pixel_count,": ", int(data))

    def run(self):
        # self.loadImage()
        # self.convertImage2Byte()
        self.printData()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Image2ByteConverter().run()
```

This Worked for me.

**Pre-requisites:**

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
python -m pip install numpy
```