# How to upload an image file to Github using PyGithub?

Tags: python, github, github-pages, github-api, pygithub

I want to upload an image file to my Github Repository using Pygithub.

```
from github import Github

g=Github("My Git Token")
repo=g.get_repo("My Repo")
content=repo.get_contents("")
f=open("1.png")
img=f.read()
repo.create_file("1.png","commit",img)
```

But I am getting the following Error:

```
File "c:\Users\mjjha\Documents\Checkrow\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 10, in <module>
    img=f.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 119: character maps to <undefined>
```

This method is working fine for text files. But I am not able to upload image files to my repository.

When I use open-CV to read the image file I get the following error:

```
    assert isinstance(content, (str, bytes))
    AssertionError
```

My Code while using cv2 is:

```
from github import Github
import cv2
g=Github("")
repo=g.get_repo("")
content=repo.get_contents("")


f=cv2.imread("1.png")
img=f
repo.create_file("1.png","commit",img)
```

I think createFile() only takes string as an arguement and thus these errors are showing up.

Is there any way to upload the image file to Github using Pygithub(or any library) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just Tested my solution and it's working

**Explanation:**
The AssertionError `assert isinstance(content, (str, bytes))`
Tells us that it only takes **string** and **bytes**.

So we just have to convert our **image** to **bytes**.

**#1 Converting image to bytearray**

```
file_path = "1.png"
with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    image_data = bytearray(f)
```

**#2 Pushing image to Github Repo by converting the data to bytes**

```
repo.create_file("1.png","commit", bytes(image_data))
```

**#CompleteCode in a Fun way**

```
from github import Github

g=Github("Git Token")
repo=g.get_repo("Repo")

file_path = "Image.png"
message = "Commit Message"
branch = "master"

with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    image_data = bytearray(f)

def push_image(path,commit_message,content,branch,update=False):
    if update:
        contents = repo.get_contents(path, ref=branch)
        repo.update_file(contents.path, commit_message, content, sha=contents.sha, branch)
    else:
        repo.create_file(path, commit_message, content, branch)


push_image(file_path,message, bytes(image_data), branch, update=False)
```

**My References For this Answer.**

1. [Converting Images to ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351973/12017533)
2. [Programmatically Update File PyGithub (StringFile Not Image)](https://martinheinz.dev/blog/25)

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is related to a wrong opening of the image file you want to upload. Try to open it with `cv2` library and passing `img` argument to the GitHub `create_file()` function:

```
f=cv2.imread("1.png")
img=f
```

Comment: `utf8` is encoding for *characters*. Opening an image with `utf8` encoding does not make sense.

Comment: `LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.open() to handle arbitrary codecs`
do you even test your code before answering or randomly writing your first *guess*?

Comment: @Asocia you should have a look at my answer. Thank you.